# data recovery from unallocated harddisk partition

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted a partition which mainly served as space I put my data, labeled D: drive. The partition wasn't subsequently formatted though, following the delete incident.

Obviously the D: drive doesn't show up as it usually does when I run Windows 7. In the "Computer Management", on clicking the Disk Management I clearly see the space is now labled as unallocated.

question: How do I go about recovering my data. Perhaps what the effective data recovery software I can use to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://lifehacker.com/5237503/five-best-free-data-recovery-tools) at lifehacker for top 5 data recovery tools

I just recently used testdisk for the first time (on ubuntu) and it worked well at finding info about my drive.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the deleted partition wasn't "extended FS" or whether that new one for Win 7 is, I have never found anything better than http://www.pcinspector.de/default.htm?language=1

And it's free

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure this will work with the partition deleted, but [Glary Undelete](http://www.glarysoft.com/gun.html) has worked wonders for me in the past, and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

TestDisk? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk. It's helped me when I aborted a resize operation on an NTFS drive (really bad idea).