# Major Data Loss, all partitions marked as unallocated after putting drives in external raid

Tags: raid, data-recovery

I had a RAID FireWire external hard drive enclosure bought for me that supports four drives.

Awesome I thought and put all my hdd's in it without a second thought, tried to use it and it the "disk wasn't readable". Fair enough I thought, guess I have to fiddle with the RAID settings etc...

I take the hard drives out put them back in my main PC and now it won't boot, so I plug one of the drives in on an external usb cable and look at it using W7 on my MBP, the entire hard drive is unallocated?!?

So I don't seem to be able to get at all my precious precious data?!?

What is the best way to go about recovering it, I'm presuming it's still there I don't know why it would have been formatted, is the MBR or the boot table just missing and needs a rebuild?!? Please offer all advice!

Extra Info: The even more annoying bit is that as these are my four main HDD's all of my data is backed up onto each of them, only a few really important bits I have stored online!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raid 0 stripes data over all the disks, so I suspect your enclosure assumes disks added are blank and makes them ready to build a 0 partition.

You could check out: 
[data recovery from unallocated harddisk partition](https://superuser.com/questions/137351/data-recovery-from-unallocated-harddisk-partition)

for some suggestions on trying to recover the information.  Alternately you will have to resort to recovering your data from your backups.